# How I can prevent an instance from invoking the constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, object, oop, constructor

I have a sample of code like this:

```
class A {
    int x{0};
    int y{0};
    
public: 
    /* A() {}; */
    
    A(int x, int y)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    };
    
    A operator+(A const &);
};

A A::operator+(A const &tmp)
{
    A t;   // HERE
        
    t.x = this->x + tmp.x;
    t.y = this->y + tmp.y;
        
    return t;
};

int main(void)
{
    A a = {1, 2};
    A b = {3, 4};
    
    A c = a+b; 
}
```

And inside the body of `A::operator+` I have this object `t`, and I wanna prevent this object from invoking `A::A()` constructor instead of initializing it as: `A t(0, 0);`. Is this possible in C++?

Comment: simply `return A{this->x + tmp.x, this->y + tmp.y};`

Comment: So you don't want any constructor call to happen but still want a new instance? And you also don't want to call the constructor with two parameters, but want to set them seperately? May I ask why?

Comment: @SHP, why you used {} instead of (), does this matter?

Comment: `A::A()` constructor is commented out.  Inside `A::operator+` cannot invoke `A::A()` constructor, because it does not exist.

Comment: @G.Sliepen • can't omit `this->` in the `A(int x, int y)` constructor, although I would change the names of the parameters so they do not shadow the member variables, and I'd use the constructor's initializer list.

Comment: @AccessDenied Just because I'd like to avoid possible [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).